# Apache Tomahawk FileUpload Not Working

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, tomahawk

I am having an issue with Apache Tomahawk - Glassfish 3.0.1 keeps logging:

> WARNING: JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, inputFileUpload.xhtml, from library, org.apache.myfaces.custom.

I have the following libraries included in /lib:

- tomahawk20-1.1.10.jar
- commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
- commons-io-1.4.jar
- commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.1.jar

Here is my web.xml.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <!-- Context Params -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.allowTextChildren</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.PRIVATE_CAPTCHA_KEY</param-name>
        <param-value>6Lfm9L4SAAAAALtVsc5E-9pvHmJueDxSXtnNahV9</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.PUBLIC_CAPTCHA_KEY</param-name>
        <param-value>6Lfm9L4SAAAAADKCm-Gi4rYLvo_B2ddLLTkvktAO</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- File Upload Paths -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>UPLOAD_DATA_URL</param-name>
        <param-value>/resources/app/uploads/data/</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>UPLOAD_DTS_URL</param-name>
        <param-value>/resources/app/uploads/dts/</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>UPLOAD_VALIDATORS_URL</param-name>
        <param-value>/resources/app/uploads/validators/</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- MS Windows-based context parameters (DEV). See PROJECT_STAGE. -->
    <context-param>
        <description>Specifies the MS Windows path separator.</description>
        <param-name>WIN_PATH_SEPARATOR</param-name>
        <param-value>\</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>Specifies the MS Windows file server path for base-level file IO.</description>
        <param-name>WIN_FILE_SVR_PATH</param-name>
        <param-value>\</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- For Apache TomaHawk MyFaces -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.CHECK_EXTENSIONS_FILTER</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.RESOURCE_VIRTUAL_PATH</param-name>
        <param-value>/faces/myFacesExtensionResource</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Filters -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>uploadMaxFileSize</param-name>
            <param-value>5m</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>uploadThresholdSize</param-name>
            <param-value>100k</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/myFacesExtensionResource/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!--
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    -->

    <!-- Servlets -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.primefaces.resource.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/primefaces_resource/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Mime Types -->
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>xls</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-excel</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>xlxs</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>doc</extension>
        <mime-type>application/msword</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>docx</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>dat</extension>
        <mime-type>application/octet-stream</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>zip</extension>
        <mime-type>application/zip</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>


    <!-- Session Management -->
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <!-- Pages -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/authenticate.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <!-- Exceptions -->
</web-app>
```

In my Facelet, I am using `xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"`, but
when browsing tags, I don't see `<t:inputFileUpload>` at all. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I wonder how to get rid of this warning... does anybody happen to know? I'm using Tomahawk, but not MyFaces (Mojarra instead).

Answer (score 1):

Tomahawk requires more JARs than that. You must have seen Tomahawk initialization warnings/errors during server startup. For example, `oro-2.0.8.jar` is also mandatory.

#### See also:

- [JSF 2.0 File upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418292/jsf-2-0-file-upload)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback BalusC! I did eventually include oro-2.0.8.jar in my classpath but no cigar. I resolved the fileupload issue by implementing your posted solution "Uploading files with JSF 2.0 and Servlet 3.0" and using an iframe. It should be noted that Netbeans nightly build > 5/30 contains a fix for parsing libraries with composite components, which caused NBs to interpret t:inputFileUpload as an error. Best to you!