# Replacement for Apache Tomahawk t:subform

Tags: jsf, tomahawk

I've been migrating away from using Tomahawk, since it has not been updated in such a very long time that it seems retired in practice if not officially.  I also get errors similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183783/apache-tomahawk-fileupload-not-working).

The only Tomahawk component that I use that I have not found a replacement for is the `t:subform` tag (see [documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/SubForm)), which I use inside of a Primefaces `p:dialog` to post back the dialog contents without validating the whole page.

Is there a replacement component or some other code/markup that will give me this ability?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the pre-existing topic, @BalusC. I probably would have had to have already been thinking of things closer to the solution to have found that question myself.  Creating an `h:panelGroup` inside the `p:dialog` and using `<p:commandButton process="..."/>` on that `h:panelGroup` as suggested in that question should do the trick.

Comment: [One of BalusC's other posts](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7372315/4266338) mentioned using multiple `<h:form>` tags on a single page, so each `<p:dialog>` entry could go in its own `<h:form>` (in addition to using `<p:commandButton ajax="true" process="..."/>`), which seems to me like an even more elegant solution.  That way, only the fields in the individual `<h:form>`(s) are posted to the server for the dialog, not all of the fields in the one big form being.